# Getting error 1070 while using UDF in pig

Tags: java, apache-pig, pig-udf

I am getting error `2017-10-29 03:34:22,212 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 6, column 13>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near ''/home/harsh/Hunny/HadoopPractice/Pig/Upper.jar''` while running pig script.

How i register and define my UDF:

```
REGISTER '/home/harsh/Hunny/HadoopPractice/Pig/Upper.jar';
DEFINE changeCase Upper();
```

My Pig script:

```
A = load 'customer1.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (name:chararray);
B = foreach A generate changeCase(name);
```

My Jar Location:

```
/home/harsh/Hunny/HadoopPractice/Pig
```

Any help is appreciated:
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing a semicolon at the end.

```
REGISTER '/home/harsh/Hunny/HadoopPractice/Pig/Upper.jar';
```

Comment: Post your entire script and UDF.Error says 6th line.What is there before the 6th line.

Comment: I was making mistake in register and define path. Its working now,
Thanks